# Расстановка знаков

Tags: пунктуация

Расставила, так как считаю правильным, верно ли? Если нет, то почему?

> Особенно сегодня - в период не простой экономической ситуации, рациональный подход к расходам, как никогда, оправдан

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему?.. Вставка оформляется симметричными знаками: открылась с тире - им же и закрылась (то же с запятой).

Точка в конце предложения не  помешала бы.

Запоминалка: "как всегда" - всегда (обособляется), "как никогда" - никогда.

(См. *как никогда* [в составе сравнительного оборота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_334).)

> Обороты «как нигде», «как никто», «как никогда» и т. п., тесно
>   связанные со сказуемым и **не имеющие при себе зависимых слов**, не
>   обособляются.

А "не простой"-то почему раздельно?

***Особенно сегодня, в период непростой экономической ситуации, рациональный подход к расходам как никогда оправдан.***

Comment: Благодарю!
 *Непростой - это опечатка. Не заметила

Comment: Надо ли искать правила на *как всегда/никогда*? См. "как всегда" вводное и в составе сказуемого: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_313